# Problema el Nombre de login no se guarda ni muestra en el segundo activity

Tags: android, android-studio, login, activity, interpolacion

Les cuento, estoy haciendo una aplicación en android studio
Todo bien pero el problema es que al colocar el Nombre en el login este no se guarda en el segundo, al no guardarse salen los simbolos de interpolado sin cambiarse al nombre como estaba programado

Imagen del segundo activity el interpolado &1$s tendria que cambiarse por el nombre que se aplique en el Login pero no se muestra y solo queda lo escrito :(
Aclaro: Tengo un nivel basico en android studio soy nuevo en esto!

Espero se pueda resolver
Desde ya gracias por la ayuda!

Aclaro: Edito esta parte debido a que falta mas codigo y quizas no sea problema de los activitys

Código primer activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mCampoNombre;
    private Button mBotonInicio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCampoNombre = findViewById(R.id.nombreEditText);
        mBotonInicio = findViewById(R.id.inicioButton);

        mBotonInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String nombre = mCampoNombre.getText().toString();
               startStory(nombre);
            }
        });


    }

    private void startStory(String nombre) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecundarioActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Nombre", nombre);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Codigo Segundo Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.realapp.modelos.Contenidos;
import com.example.realapp.modelos.Pagina;

public class SecundarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String mNombre;
    private Contenidos mContenidos = new Contenidos() ;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mOpcion1;
    private Button mOpcion2;
    private Pagina mPaginaActiva;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secundario);

        Intent intent = getIntent () ;
        mNombre = intent.getStringExtra("Nombre");
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ContenidoImageView);
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ContenidoTextView);
        mOpcion1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcionButton1);
        mOpcion2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opcionButton2);

        loadpage(0);



    }

    private void loadpage(int i) {
        mPaginaActiva = mContenidos.getPage(i);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mPaginaActiva.getImageId());
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        String pageText = mPaginaActiva.getText();
        pageText = String.format(pageText, mNombre);

        mTextView.setText(pageText);

        if (mPaginaActiva.IsFinal()) {
            mOpcion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mOpcion2.setText("INTENTARLO DE NUEVO");
            mOpcion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });


        } else {

        mOpcion1.setText(mPaginaActiva.getOpcion1().getText());
        mOpcion2.setText(mPaginaActiva.getOpcion2().getText());

        mOpcion1.setOnClickListener( (v) -> {
        int nextPage = mPaginaActiva.getOpcion1().getNextPage();
        loadpage(nextPage);
            }) ;

        mOpcion2.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            int nextPage = mPaginaActiva.getOpcion2().getNextPage();
            loadpage(nextPage);

        });
    }


}}
```

Codigo Pagina:

```
public class Pagina {
    private int mImageId; // id de la imagen
    private String mText; // id del string, creamos ahora la lase de Opcion
    private Opcion mOpcion1;
    private Opcion mOpcion2;
    private boolean mIsFinal = false;

    public Pagina(int ImageId, String Text, Opcion Opcion1, Opcion Opcion2) {
        mImageId = ImageId;
        mText = Text;
        mOpcion1 = Opcion1;
        mOpcion2 = Opcion2;
    }

    public boolean IsFinal(){return mIsFinal;}
    public void setIsFinal (boolean isFinal) {mIsFinal=isFinal;}
    public Pagina(int ImageId, String Text) {
        mImageId = ImageId;
        mText = Text;
        mOpcion1 = null;
        mOpcion2 = null;
        mIsFinal = true;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return mImageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int ImageId) {
        mImageId = ImageId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String Text) {
        mText = Text;
    }

    public Opcion getOpcion1() {
        return mOpcion1;
    }

    public void setOpcion1(Opcion Opcion1) { mOpcion1 = Opcion1;
    }

    public Opcion getOpcion2() {
        return mOpcion2;
    }

    public void setOpcion2(Opcion Opcion2) { mOpcion2 = Opcion2;
    }
}
```

Codigo Opción:

```
public class Opcion {
    private String mText;
    private int mNextPage;

    public Opcion(String Text, int NextPage) {
        mText = Text;
        mNextPage = NextPage;
    }

    public Opcion(String juego_finalizado) {

    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public void setText(String Text) {
        mText = Text;
    }

    public int getNextPage() {
        return mNextPage;
    }

    public void setNextPage(int NextPage) {
        mNextPage = NextPage;
    }
}
```

Codigo Contenido:

```
public class Contenidos {

    private Pagina[] mPaginas;

    public Contenidos() {
        mPaginas = new Pagina[8];

        mPaginas[0] = new Pagina (
                R.drawable.img0,
                "Hola &1$S, Aqui comienza tu historia ¿Podras sobrevivir? o ¿Moriras en el intento Tu país a sido bombardeado, tu unica esperanza es refugiarte en un bunker antiguo..       " + "                 ☣¿Que decides hacer?☣",
                new Opcion("Recoger Reservas", 1),
                new Opcion("Entrar En El Bunker",2));


        mPaginas[1] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img1,
                "Recoges las reservas y tan solo 30 segundos despues tienes todo lo necesario ¿Aprovechas el tiempo o Vuelves al Bunker?",
                new Opcion("Ir al Bunker", 3),
                new Opcion("Buscar Mas Recursos",4));

        mPaginas[2] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img2,
                "Entras al bunker y logras sobrevivir, sin embargo tus reservas se estan acabando y hay una fuerte tormenta, te pones nervioso y piensas en una decisión",
                new Opcion("Quedarte en el bunker", 5),
                new Opcion("Salir a explorar",6));

        mPaginas[3] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img3,
                "Decides entrar al bunker justo antes de que una tormenta destruya todo el exterior ¡Bien Hecho!, tienes muchas reservas, pero la soledad te deprime, pasan los dias y la tormenta calmo, ¿que decides?",
                new Opcion("Salir a Explorar", 6),
                new Opcion("Esperas un poco mas en tu bunker",5));

        mPaginas[4] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img4,
                "Te Dispones a buscar mas recursos pero de repente escuchas un estruendo! ¡Pum! ¡Plak! ¡Plik! una tormenta te atrapa y tu historia llega a su final.");


        mPaginas[5] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img5,
                "Tus reservas son casi-inexistentes estas tirado sin poder moverte, el agua se te a acabado hace 3 días, pero de repente vez una luz entrando desde la puerta... ¡Felicidades! Has sobrevivido! un grupo de militares de la region busca civiles y te han encontrado, te llevan al centro de rehabilitacion donde pasaras unos días hasta que te pongas bien, luego te das cuenta que eres uno de los pocos supervivientes, tiempo despues te llaman de una editorial para que hagas un libro a cerca de los hechos, te vuelves famoso y vives para contar tu historia...Esta historia a llegado a su fin.");

        mPaginas[6] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img6,
                 "Sales a explorar dispuesto a encontrar algo, la tormenta es casi nula y te adentras en la zona pero descubres que no estas solo, te encuentras con lo que parecen ser zombies, estas cansando y terminas siendo el almuerzo de ellos, tu historia llega a su fin" );





    }

    public Pagina getPage(int pageNumber){
        return mPaginas[pageNumber];
    }
}
```

Problema: El &1$s no se cambia por el nombre que se inserta en el login es decir en el Primer activity
Algo esta interrumpiendo ese avance o me estoy confundiendo en algo
Edito y dejo los demas .java por si no son los principales
Saludos y gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Problema solucionado
Solución: El Interpolado con símbolos (&1$s) era interrumpido por unos simbolos txt que habia puesto como decorativos ☣☣
Ahora si llega el nombre
Era un error bastante simple pero un poco desordenado para novatos como yo
Suerte y gracias por la ayuda :)!

Comment: Un consejo para el futuro, NUNCA utilices este tipo de caracteres, cuando tengas que manipular textos si no quieres tener muchos errores, ademas no deberias permitir que los usuarios introduzcan estos caracteres, ni emojis, en un sistema de login, por seguridad y estabilidad de la aplicación .Ademas deberias controlar los acentos, signos de puntuación, apostrofes, etc.... ya que algunos de estos caracteres en base de datos con mysql , pueden dar problemas....